# IP address and hostname of remote peer in Twisted TCP client

Tags: python, twisted

Writing a Jabber client that uses Twisted Words. I would like to know an IP address and hostname of remote peer. `xmlstream.transport.getPeer().host` return hostname, while it should return IP address (`xmlstream` is an instance of `twisted.words.protocols.jabber.xmlstream.XmlStream`).

**Update:** Yes, my Twisted is rather outdated, from Ubuntu Hardy package:

```
$ python -c "import twisted; print twisted.__version__"
2.5.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've run into [a bug fixed 3 years ago, in Twisted 8.2.0](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3059).  You should upgrade to a more recent version of Twisted.  (I would suggest the [recently-announced prerelease of Twisted 11.0](http://labs.twistedmatrix.com/2011/03/twisted-1100pre1-released-please-test.html); now's a good time to test!)  If you've found this bug in a more recent version of Twisted, you should reopen that bug, and explain how to reproduce it!

If you need to support whatever older version of Twisted you're using, rather than `socket`, which is an accidentally-exposed implementation detail of your `ITransport` implementation, you should use [`getHandle`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.tcp.Connection.html#getHandle), which is at least the *documented*, public way to get at this implementation-dependent stuff, like this:

```
self.xmlstream.transport.getHandle().getpeername()
```

Note that this will not work on some reactors, notably the IOCP reactor, which [uses something other than BSD sockets](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.iocpreactor.tcp.Connection.html#getHandle) for its network communication.

(Jean-Paul already noted most of this in a comment, but I felt this should show up as an answer.)

Comment: Ok, getPeer works correctly in recent Twisted. Then how do I get **hostname** of my TCP peer? I want to write code that will work correctly in old and new versions.

Comment: Resolve the IP address, probably with twisted.names.client.lookupPointer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I'll answer my own question. Had to go to underlying socket to get IP address:

```
ip, port = self.xmlstream.transport.socket.getpeername()
```

It's <del>likely</del> a bug Twisted TCP client that getPeer doesn't work correctly.

And I use getPeer() to get hostname. Yes, it's bad - I'm relying on old and buggy behaviour. Please enlighten me - how do it properly in new version of Twisted?

Comment: This won't always work.  It sounds like you ran in to <http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/3059>, which was fixed in Twisted 8.2.0.  If you're experiencing this problem in a later version of Twisted, please file a bug report!